# How to set minimum weight of order in woocommerce?

Tags: wordpress

How to get Woo Commerce product variation values in WordPress .I've three values 250g,500g and 1kg.
I've restrict on checkout process 500g.

Comment: This is a repost of [How to Set Purchase Limits which a minimum weight requirement before checking out in WordPress Woo commerce/?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59857293/how-to-set-purchase-limits-which-a-minimum-weight-requirement-before-checking-ou)

Answer (score 0):

Add this code to functions.php. You may check article [here](https://logicdigger.com/how-to-set-minimum-weight-in-woocommerce-orders/)

```
 add_action( 'woocommerce_check_cart_items', 'cldws_set_weight_requirements' );
    function cldws_set_weight_requirements() {
     // Only run in the Cart or Checkout pages
     if( is_cart() || is_checkout() ) {
     global $woocommerce;
     // Set the minimum weight before checking out
     $minimum_weight = 500;
     // Get the Cart's content total weight
     $cart_contents_weight = WC()->cart->cart_contents_weight;
     // Compare values and add an error is Cart's total weight
     if( $cart_contents_weight < $minimum_weight  ) {
     // Display our error message
     wc_add_notice( sprintf('<strong>A Minimum Weight of %s%s is required before checking out.</strong>'
     . '<br />Current cart weight: %s%s',
     $minimum_weight,
     get_option( 'woocommerce_weight_unit' ),
     $cart_contents_weight,
     get_option( 'woocommerce_weight_unit' ),
     get_permalink( wc_get_page_id( 'shop' ) )
     ),
     'error' );
     }
     }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Where Can I add this code in file?

Comment: You can implement like this. Or provide me complete detail how do you want use. Where to display

Comment: I want to add on checkout process when user checkout it will generate a message that minimum weight values buy 500g not 250g .

Comment: Checkout button will show when user buy 500g or more. I cant still get variable products attributes values.when i used above code  that no display anything  its show empty?

Comment: ok got it . give me minutes

Comment: Please check new code

Comment: have you tested?

Comment: Yes but not working as I need